# Self loop in view serializability polygraph?

Tags: database, transactions

I have the following schedule:

```
Transaction T1          Transaction T2          Transaction T3

Write (A)     

                        Write (B)

Read  (C)

                        Read (B)

                                                Read (B)
```

You can notice that the writing source of B for Read(B) in T2, is T2 itsef. Do I have to draw a self loop on T2 in the polygraph for testing view serializability? If yes, can I always say that the schedule is not view serializable when the source of a read is the reading transaction itself, because of the self loop in the polygrah?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer should be this: in the polygraph there is an edge between Ti e Tj only if Tj reads a variable written by Ti, but Ti and Tj must be different transactions. So there are never self loop in the polygraph.